# Update table column with data from other columns in same row

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that has several columns of textual data. The goal is to concatenate those columns into a single different column in the same table and same row.

What is the SQL Server query syntax that would allow me to do this?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? You want to store redundant data that you can calculate at query time (using a view if you do it often)? Have you considered a computed column at least?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand, see my comment on your answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this:

```
UPDATE myTable SET X = Y + Z
```

Comment: but how would i query the same table to get the data from the other columns?

Comment: does y and z in your example refer to columns or values?

Comment: ok i see, you dont need to do a sub select. gotcha. this works.

Comment: an interesting point to note, all of the fields in the concatenation must contain a value. if any are NULL, the whole field is set to null.

Comment: @Jason Miesionczek: Re Null: If you don't want that behavior, wrap the columns in a coalesce like so: `update myTable set X = coalesce(Y, '') + coalesce(Z, '')`

Comment: Or you can say `...SET X = COALESCE(Y, '') + COALESCE(Z, '')`

Answer (score 3):

Do you absolutely have to duplicate your data? If one of the column values changes, you will have to update the concatenated value.

A computed column:

```
alter table dbo.MyTable add ConcatenatedColumn = ColumnA + ColumnB
```

Or a view:

```
create view dbo.MyView as
select ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnA + ColumnB as 'ConcatenatedColumn'
from dbo.MyTable
```

Now you can update ColumnA or ColumnB, and ConcatenatedColumn will always be in sync. If that's the behaviour you need, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Might be misunderstanding but:

```
Alter table myTable add combinedColumn Varchar(1000);

Update myTable set combinedColumn = textField1 + textField2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
  textfield1 + textfield2 + ... + textfieldN as conc_text,
  otherfield1,
  otherfield2,
  ...
  otherfieldN
from 
  mytable
```

Comment: i should clarify, the goal is to update a different, existing column, with the concatenated text data

Comment: But you should explain WHY that is the goal. Why do you want to store the same data twice?

Comment: the data is in a column that is consistently named among several tables for use in an internal search function. if all the text data is contained in one column, it makes searching different tables with different kinds of data much easier.

Comment: So make a computed column with that name, or a view with a column with that name. Do you really want to repeat your update every time any of the column data changes? This is just wasted work.